# Jupyter In and Out Style

Tags: python

I searched for a smiliar topic or a package, but I've found none. I write a thesis about a program I wrote and used Jupyter Notebooks. Now I'd like to have environments in the style of Notebooks, namely:

```
ln [1]: print('Hello World!')
out[1]: Hello World!
```

with the same colors and python highlighting. Is there a short and concise way to do this? Maybe there is a package already?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Since I am learning python, TeX, and with Jupyter; oýou should be informed about PythonTeX package, that is essential for integrating python and TeX. Your goal should be achievable also with minted package (maybe even listings). But PythonTeX gives you full python into TeX integration.

Comment: Thanks! This is good to know. Unfortunately this is not what I am looking for. I'm using the SageMath package (which has indeed its own LaTeX package). However, I want the Jupyter Notebook design integrated in my LaTeX document. The computations are done elsewhere and take in addition pretty much time so that I will put everything together manually anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jupyter Lab has an <kbd>Export Notebook to LaTeX</kbd> option in the <kbd>File</kbd> menu:

[image]

This creates a standalone file with a very large preamble (with color definitions, box drawing settings, etc), and the Notebook blocks in the body, such as:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, size=fbox, boxrule=1pt, pad at break*=1mm,colback=cellbackground, colframe=cellborder]
\prompt{In}{incolor}{1}{\boxspacing}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\PY{n+nb}{print}\PY{p}{(}\PY{l+s+s1}{\PYZsq{}}\PY{l+s+s1}{Hello World!}\PY{l+s+s1}{\PYZsq{}}\PY{p}{)}
\end{Verbatim}
\end{tcolorbox}

    \begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
Hello World!
    \end{Verbatim}
```

rendering as

[image]

You can copy the preamble to your own document (or save it to a separate file and use `\input`) and then you should be able to use the block snippets in your own document as well. Of course the exact procedure may depend a bit on what your actual document looks like.

Comment: Awesome, I did not know about that! Mr. Marijn, does it use PythonTeX, or is the document exported like that compilable without it?

Comment: @TomášKruliš PythonTeX is not used. As you can see in the example, both the Python code (first `\begin{Verbatim}`/`\end{Verbatim}` block) and the result (second `\begin{Verbatim}`/`\end{Verbatim}` block) are contained in the LaTeX code.