# Last line in fancyvrb has weird spacing

Tags: listings, verbatim, python

I still try to make a Jupyter environment (see [Jupyter In and Out Style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514098/jupyter-in-and-out-style)).

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[english,twoside,a4paper]{scrartcl}

%-------
%   Typography
%-------

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

%-------
%   Notebook Styling
%-------

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\lstdefinestyle{NBoutput}{
    basicstyle={\linespread{1}\small\ttfamily},
    fancyvrb=true,
    basewidth=0.5em,
}

\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{nobeforeafter} % prevents tcolorboxes being placing in paragraphs

\definecolor{outcolor}{HTML}{D84315}

% prompt
\newcommand{\prompt}[4]{
    \llap{{\small\texttt{\color{#2}#1[#3]:#4}}}\vspace{-1em}
}

\newcounter{NBin}

\newenvironment{NotebookOut}{\refstepcounter{NBin}
    \VerbatimEnvironment
    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, boxrule=.5pt, size=fbox, pad at break*=1mm, opacityfill=0]
    \prompt{}{outcolor}{\theNBin}{\hspace{5.5pt}}
    \lstset{style=NBoutput}
    \begin{Verbatim}
}{
    \end{Verbatim}
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{NotebookOut}
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
\end{NotebookOut}

\end{document}
```

Somehow, the very last line is always skipped a bit which is certainly not desired.

Also, I've tried other packages like minted or listing, but they seem not to work for other reasons.

Apart from that, I appreciate any improvements of the code.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example? Would perhaps changing `\vspace{-1.05em}` to `\vspace{-1em}` in the definition of your `\prompt` macro work?

Comment: No. But leaving out "fancyvrb=true" in the lstdefinestyle works. However, the highlighting is not working then.

Comment: Voilà, I provided a minimal example. :)

Comment: What's the purpose of doing `\lstset` and then using `Verbatim`?

Comment: I have no idea, I just copied some examples I've found in the net. Moreover, lstlisting doesn't work with declaring new environments. I am a complete newbie in using Verbatim and stuff.

Comment: This seems to be a conflict of the two packages `listings` and `fancyvrb`. You should perhaps use rather only one of them.

Comment: Do you have another code suggestion then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that this spurious space is due to the use of `listings` and `fancyvrb` that somehow clash here. Why don’t you just use the `listings` library that comes with the `tcolorbox` package? (Although your example above does not show it really, I know that you use other boxes with background and color that need `tcolorbox`, which is why I propose this solution here.)

So, a possible solution with just `tcolorbox` would be:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{scrartcl}

%-------
%   Typography
%-------

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

%-------
%   Notebook Styling
%-------

\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\tcbset{nobeforeafter} 

\definecolor{outcolor}{HTML}{D84315}

\newcommand{\prompt}[4]{%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\texttt{\color{#2}#1[#3]:#4}}\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
}

\newcounter{NBin}

\newtcblisting{NotebookOut}{
    breakable,
    boxrule=.5pt, 
    size=fbox, 
    pad at break*=1mm, 
    opacityfill=1,
    phantom=\refstepcounter{NBin},
    title=\prompt{}{outcolor}{\theNBin}{\hspace{5.5pt}},
    fonttitle=\linespread{1}\small,
    attach title to upper,
    listing only,
    listing options={
        language=python,
        basicstyle=\linespread{1}\small\ttfamily,
        basewidth=.5em,
        aboveskip=0pt,
        belowskip=0pt,
        showstringspaces=false,
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{NotebookOut}
echo "Hello World!";
echo "Hello World!";
\end{NotebookOut}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I'd use `fonttitle=\lnespread{1}\small`, remove `\small` from the definition of `\prompt` and type `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` instead of guessing `-1.1em`.

Comment: Thanks egreg! I made an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You define and use a variant of fancyvrb's `Verbatim` environment.

You also use the listings-package's interface to fancyvrb. (The `fancyvrb=true`-thingie.)

According to the manual of the listings-package this means that the internals of the **fancyvrb**-package are used for **reading** the code-listing from the .tex-file/from the sources and the internals of the **listings**-package are used for **typesetting** the code-listing.

Seems when the internals of the lisitings-package typeset the last line of your listing, the baselineskip calculated due to `basicstyle={\linespread{1}\small\ttfamily}` is not in effect any more.

Instead erroneously the baselineskip due to `\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}` with `\normalfont`/`\normalsize` is in effect.

This might be a bug in the listings-package's interface to fancyvrb.

You can test this by restoring the basicstyle right before printing the last line by patching the macro `\FV@ListProcessLastLine`:

```
\documentclass[english,twoside,a4paper]{scrartcl}

%-------
%   Typography
%-------

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

%-------
%   Notebook Styling
%-------

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\lstdefinestyle{NBoutput}{
    basicstyle={\linespread{1}\small\ttfamily},
    fancyvrb=true,
    basewidth=0.5em,
}

\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{nobeforeafter} % prevents tcolorboxes being placing in paragraphs

\definecolor{outcolor}{HTML}{D84315}

% prompt
\newcommand{\prompt}[4]{%
    \llap{{\small\texttt{\color{#2}#1[#3]:#4}}}\vspace{-1em}%
}

\newcounter{NBin}

\newenvironment{NotebookOut}{\refstepcounter{NBin}%
    \VerbatimEnvironment%
    \lstset{style=NBoutput}%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, boxrule=.5pt, size=fbox, pad at break*=1mm, opacityfill=0]%
    \prompt{}{outcolor}{\theNBin}{\hspace{5.5pt}}%
    \begin{Verbatim}%
}{%
    \end{Verbatim}\end{tcolorbox}%
}%

% For testing-purposes patch \FV@ListProcessLastLine to restore NBoutput's basicstyle:
\makeatletter
\def\FV@ListProcessLastLine{%
  \begingroup
  % Here the patching:
  \linespread{1}\small\ttfamily
  %
  \ifx\FV@ProcessLine\FV@ListProcessLine@iv
    {\advance\interlinepenalty\widowpenalty
     \penalty\interlinepenalty}%
    \box\@tempboxa
  \else
    \ifx\FV@ProcessLine\FV@ListProcessLine@iii
      {\advance\interlinepenalty\widowpenalty
       \advance\interlinepenalty\clubpenalty
       \penalty\interlinepenalty}%
      \box\@tempboxa 
    \else
      \ifx\FV@ProcessLine\FV@ListProcessLine@i
        \FV@Error{Empty verbatim environment}{}\FV@ProcessLine{}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \endgroup
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{NotebookOut}
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
\end{NotebookOut}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also test this by making `\linespread{1}\small\ttfamily` efffective within the scope of your environment no matter if `\lstset`-settings are effective or not:

```
\documentclass[english,twoside,a4paper]{scrartcl}

%-------
%   Typography
%-------

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

%-------
%   Notebook Styling
%-------

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\lstdefinestyle{NBoutput}{
    basicstyle={\linespread{1}\small\ttfamily},
    fancyvrb=true,
    basewidth=0.5em,
}

\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{nobeforeafter} % prevents tcolorboxes being placing in paragraphs

\definecolor{outcolor}{HTML}{D84315}

% prompt
\newcommand{\prompt}[4]{%
    \llap{{\small\texttt{\color{#2}#1[#3]:#4}}}\vspace{-1em}%
}

\newcounter{NBin}

\newenvironment{NotebookOut}{\refstepcounter{NBin}%
    \VerbatimEnvironment%
    % Make \linespread{1}\small\ttfamily effective no matter if \lstset-settings are in effect or not:
    \begingroup
    \linespread{1}\small\ttfamily
    \lstset{style=NBoutput}%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, boxrule=.5pt, size=fbox, pad at break*=1mm, opacityfill=0]%
    \prompt{}{outcolor}{\theNBin}{\hspace{5.5pt}}%
    \begin{Verbatim}%
}{%
    \end{Verbatim}\end{tcolorbox}%
    \endgroup
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{NotebookOut}
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
\end{NotebookOut}

\end{document}
```

[image]