# Jupyter In/Out without Overflowing

Tags: verbatim, python

In [Jupyter In and Out Style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514098/jupyter-in-and-out-style) and [Last line in fancyvrb has weird spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516412/last-line-in-fancyvrb-has-weird-spacing/) I asked for a neat solution to realize a Jupyter style within LaTeX.

That's great so far and works quite good and solid. However, it would be perfect to have the input/output numbers not overflowing on the left. Is that possible without too much effort?

The minimal example I am working with is adopted from the answer in [Last line in fancyvrb has weird spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516412/last-line-in-fancyvrb-has-weird-spacing/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the `tcolorbox` to the right by specifying a `left skip`.  In the code below I have provide two lengths for the width of the prompt and its separation from the output box.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{scrartcl}

%-------
%   Typography
%-------

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

%-------
%   Notebook Styling
%-------

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\tcbset{nobeforeafter}

\definecolor{outcolor}{HTML}{D84315}

\newlength{\promptwidth}
\setlength{\promptwidth}{30pt}
\newlength{\promptsep}
\setlength{\promptsep}{5.5pt}

\newcommand{\prompt}[4]{%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\texttt{\color{#2}#1[#3]:#4}}\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
}

\newcounter{NBin}

\newtcblisting{NotebookOut}{
    breakable,
    boxrule=.5pt,
    size=fbox,
    left skip = \promptwidth + \promptsep,
    pad at break*=1mm,
    opacityfill=1,
    phantom=\refstepcounter{NBin},
    title=\prompt{}{outcolor}{\theNBin}{\hspace{\promptsep}},
    fonttitle=\linespread{1}\small,
    attach title to upper,
    listing only,
    listing options={
        language=python,
        basicstyle=\linespread{1}\small\ttfamily,
        basewidth=.5em,
        aboveskip=0pt,
        belowskip=0pt,
        showstringspaces=false,
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{NotebookOut}
print('Hello World!')
print('Hello World!')
\end{NotebookOut}

\noindent
Text
\begin{NotebookOut}
print('Hello World!')
print('Hello World!')
\end{NotebookOut}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "left skip" does the job. Thanks so far. However is it possible to keep this flexible when the the number of digits changes in the prompt? Best option: The prompt always left aligned attached to the text.

Comment: The standard jupyter style is right-aligned in a box of some fixed width.  The other option is possible.  Do want the code box to stay a fixed size, or shrink in width as the number of digits increases?

Comment: Mhh. That's difficult. What do you prefer from an aesthetical and typographical point of view? 
Or would you keep it overflowed?

Comment: I prefer the version I have given, keeping the code box the same size with the same indent.  One should adjust the prompt width to fit the widest label you expect and/or the general document style.

Comment: Thanks. Even though I'm really grateful you answered my question, I probably prefer another solution. Anyway, at least I have a clue now how to handle this. Thanks again! :)