# Jupyter In/Out style using minted instead of listing

Tags: formatting, listings, minted, python

In [Jupyter In/Out without Overflowing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521607/jupyter-in-out-without-overflowing?newreg=8110a09c2b6c45feb2eeb22bba32ccf6) the solution provided is excellent. I'm implementing it using the minted option in tcbuselibrary and I'm getting this extra whitespace at the beginning of my source code that I don't get with listings.

I'd like to know if there's a way to implement this while having the colon of 'Out:' aligned with my first line of code as it's done using listings in the first answer to this post [Jupyter In/Out without Overflowing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521607/jupyter-in-out-without-overflowing?newreg=8110a09c2b6c45feb2eeb22bba32ccf6).

My MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}
\tcbset{nobeforeafter}

\definecolor{outcolor}{HTML}{D84315}

\newlength{\promptwidth}
\setlength{\promptwidth}{30pt}
\newlength{\promptsep}
\setlength{\promptsep}{5.5pt}

\newcommand{\prompt}[4]{%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\texttt{\color{#2}#1[#3]:#4}}\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
}

\newcounter{NBout}

\newtcblisting{NotebookOut}{
    breakable,
    boxrule=.5pt,
    size=fbox,
    left skip = \promptwidth + \promptsep,
    pad at break*=1mm,
    opacityfill=1,
    phantom=\refstepcounter{NBout},
    title=\prompt{Out}{outcolor}{\theNBin}{\hspace{\promptsep}},
    fonttitle=\linespread{1}\small,
    attach title to upper,
    listing only,
    minted language = python,
}




\begin{document}


\begin{NotebookOut}
import math as m 

A =[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(3):
        A[i][j] = m.sin(i*j)
        
print(A)
\end{NotebookOut}



\end{document}
```

this is a snap of what I get [image: minted environment]

While I'm still using the minted option, my objective is to have the 'Out:' aligned with the word 'import'.Is this possible, or am I missing something?
I appreciate your assistance, and any suggestions for my code are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main adjustment is to the `\vspace` in the definition of `\prompt`, it seems that in your set-up a larger negative space of `-1.7\baselineskip` is appropriate (judged by eye).  I would also suggest you increase the `\promptwidth` and probably drop the `nobeforeafter` to get

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}
%\tcbset{nobeforeafter}

\definecolor{outcolor}{HTML}{D84315}

\newlength{\promptwidth}
\setlength{\promptwidth}{45pt}
\newlength{\promptsep}
\setlength{\promptsep}{5.5pt}

\newcommand{\prompt}[4]{%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\texttt{\color{#2}#1[#3]:#4}}\vspace{-1.7\baselineskip}%
}

\newcounter{NBout}

\newtcblisting{NotebookOut}{
    breakable,
    boxrule=.5pt,
    size=fbox,
    left skip = \promptwidth + \promptsep,
    pad at break*=1mm,
    opacityfill=1,
    phantom=\refstepcounter{NBout},
    title=\prompt{Out}{outcolor}{\theNBout}{\hspace{\promptsep}},
    fonttitle=\linespread{1}\small,
    attach title to upper,
    listing only,
    minted language = python,
}

\begin{document}


\begin{NotebookOut}
import math as m

A =[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(3):
        A[i][j] = m.sin(i*j)

print(A)
\end{NotebookOut}

\noindent Text

\begin{NotebookOut}
import math as m

A =[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(3):
        A[i][j] = m.sin(i*j)

print(A)
\end{NotebookOut}



\end{document}
```