# How can I embed python (ipynb) foxes in LaTeX so that I get both my output and input showing like it would in a Jupyter Lab or similar environment?

Tags: overleaf, python

Is there any package for the same? I need this to formate the homework for a class which is in a Python file. So, ideally, I should be able to embed the file within the LaTeX (Overleaf) environment but the code should look like it's in Jupyter. I don't wanna code in Python within LaTeX, I just want my file to be embeded within the Overleaf environment and appear as if it was in the Jupyter environment.

Comment: What is Python foxes? The following link may be relevant:
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/code_listing

Comment: Hello, and welcome to TeX StackExchange! Would this be of help to you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/514098/218142